# "dirname: missing operand" error while starting mongod service

Tags: mongodb

I recently installed mongo 2.6.5 version on our Red Hat enterprise Linux server. Everything was working fine, until I decided to make a change in /etc/mongod.conf file. I noticed that from version 2.6 above mongo supports conf file in YAML fomat. (the reason I wanted to make a change was, I wanted to enable the authentication on mongo instance)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

I changed my config file which used to look like below (I am adding only a portion of the config):

```mongo
# mongod.conf

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

# fork and run in background
fork=true

#port=27017

dbpath=/var/lib/mongo

# location of pidfile
pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

My changed file mongod.conf file looks like below now:

```mongo
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true

storage:
    dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo"
    journal:
        enabled: true

processManagement:
    pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid"
    fork: true

security:
    authorization: true![enter image description here][1]
```

Now when I try to run the mongod service it is giving me error (see attached picture):
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information
Starting mongod: [FAILED]

When I  revert my mongod.conf file to previous version, then the service runs fine. Do I need to change something in my mongo installation to make it use YAML format of config?

Comment: The conf looks good. `dirname` is a command line program - which makes it sound like the problem is with how you're running the service. Have you looked into that?

Comment: I don't see your attachment, but I just suddenly got this, although mongod started anyway. Did this coincidence with a kernel update by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

1. make sure that you define a PID file location in /etc/mongod.conf

   ```
   pidfilepath=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
   ```
2. change the "daemon" line in /etc/init.d/mongod to explicitly use the PID file

   ```
   daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" --check "$mongod" --pidfile "$PIDFILE" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"
   ```

In addition, ensure that the following are all owned by mongod

- /var/log/mongodb
- /var/run/mongodb
- your dbpath

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that although mongod supports YAML config files, the initscripts haven't been revised to handle them.

Answer (score 2):

I have been tracking this same issue down with mongo 2.6.5 on Centos 6.6.  The error is coming from `/etc/init.d/functions` when it is trying to find the program's base name and then subsequently automatically generate a PID file.  That's being called by `daemon` like so:

```
daemon --user mongod ' /usr/bin/mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

The base variable grabs everything after the last slash and the pidfile defaults to base + ".pid".  Normally you may execute something like this:

```
daemon --user nobody /usr/bin/some-service
# base:  some-service
# pid file:  some-service.pid
```

For mongo, the base variable is set to "null 2>&1" and then running `basename null 2>&1` results in the error you are seeing.  The easiest way to fix this is to specify the actual binary that you intend to run using the `--check` command-line argument to `daemon`.  Edit `/etc/init.d/mongod` and search around line 111:

```
# Old version
#daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"

# New, working version
daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" --check "$mongod" "$NUMACTL $mongod $OPTIONS >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Without digging too much further into the issue, it looks like this argument is missing due to an oversight.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Jira issue for this bug, [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13595).

They have a nice workaround of changing the REGEX that's used to find the values in the config file.